# Why does the C# compiler allow me to access private fields of an object inside of an operator method?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors

I have this class:

```
class Foo
    {
        private int _value;

        public static int operator +(Foo foo1, Foo foo2)
        {
            return foo1._value + foo2._value;
        }
    }
```

Why am I able to access `foo1._value`, which is explicitly declared as `private`?

Comment: Access levels determine which _types_ (classes / structs / interfaces) may access things, not which _objects_ may access things. Even though `foo1` and `foo2` are private, the operator declared in the `Foo` class may access them.

Answer (score 0):

It is private to `Foo`. Your method is part of `Foo`, hence it has full access to itself. If no method of `Foo` could touch that field: it could never be used at all.